# Different image heights for different resolutions without distortion

Tags: images

In Meta Slider for WP as in most sliders, the height is defined once and for all in dashboard. Sometimes though a full-width slider can look too thin on a mobile, but if you increase the height "manually" then the image becomes vertically distorted.

Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. If you need to use smaller images for mobile then nothing is stopping you from doing that.

Comment: Not smaller images, rather taller images. My issue is with proportions: the slider images look like thin horizontal bands on a mobile, I want them to be like twice as tall or more. If for example I change their height with Firebug the image gets distorted.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no force in the universe that prevents you from serving taller versions to mobile. The question is not clear, what do you exactly expect the answer to be, that people here will send threat letters to the plugin authors to change their code? ;) You know you should serve taller images, so serve them